# pip-compile fails while parsing base.py

Tags: pip-tools

This is the first time I try to use [`pip-compile` from `pip-tools`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/).

The base-level settings for a Django project are provided in `main/settings/base.py`. I added this section for `pip-tools`:

```py
install_requires = [
    'django-oscar>=3.0.2,<4.0.0',
    'boto3==1.17.27',
    'psycopg2-binary==2.8.6',
    'pycountry==20.7.3',
]
```

`pip-compile` blows up when I try to use it. How might this be fixed?

```
$ pip-compile main/settings/base.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 113, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3250, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(abcd...), found '"'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 342, in parse_req_from_line
    req = Requirement(req_as_string)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 115, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'"""'": Expected W:(abcd...)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/bin/pip-compile", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/piptools/scripts/compile.py", line 369, in cli
    constraints.extend(
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/piptools/_compat/pip_compat.py", line 26, in parse_requirements
    yield install_req_from_parsed_requirement(parsed_req, isolated=isolated)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 458, in install_req_from_parsed_requirement
    req = install_req_from_line(
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 391, in install_req_from_line
    parts = parse_req_from_line(name, line_source)
  File "/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 357, in parse_req_from_line
    raise InstallationError(msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Invalid requirement: '"""' (from line 1 of main/settings/base.py)
```

Update 1: I get the same error for this section:

```py
install_requires = [
]
```

Update 2: I made a file called `requirements.in` like this:

```
django-oscar>=3.0.2,<4.0.0
boto3==1.17.27
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pycountry==20.7.3
```

... and `requirements.txt` was generated properly:

```
$ pip-compile
# Long pause...

$ cat requirements.txt
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile
#
asgiref==3.3.1
    # via django
babel==2.9.0
    # via
    #   django-oscar
    #   django-phonenumber-field
boto3==1.17.27
    # via -r requirements.in
botocore==1.20.45
    # via
    #   boto3
    #   s3transfer
django-extra-views==0.13.0
    # via django-oscar
django-haystack==3.0
    # via django-oscar
django-oscar==3.0.2
    # via -r requirements.in
django-phonenumber-field==3.0.1
    # via django-oscar
django-tables2==2.3.4
    # via django-oscar
django-treebeard==4.4
    # via django-oscar
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
    # via django-oscar
django==3.1.7
    # via
    #   django-extra-views
    #   django-haystack
    #   django-oscar
    #   django-phonenumber-field
    #   django-tables2
    #   django-treebeard
factory-boy==2.12.0
    # via django-oscar
faker==6.4.1
    # via factory-boy
jmespath==0.10.0
    # via
    #   boto3
    #   botocore
phonenumbers==8.12.18
    # via django-oscar
pillow==8.1.0
    # via django-oscar
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
    # via -r requirements.in
purl==1.5
    # via django-oscar
pycountry==20.7.3
    # via -r requirements.in
python-dateutil==2.8.1
    # via
    #   botocore
    #   faker
pytz==2021.1
    # via
    #   babel
    #   django
s3transfer==0.3.6
    # via boto3
six==1.15.0
    # via
    #   django-extra-views
    #   purl
    #   python-dateutil
sqlparse==0.4.1
    # via django
text-unidecode==1.3
    # via faker
urllib3==1.26.4
    # via botocore
```

Is `pip-tools` parsing of `setup.py` broken?

Comment: [Opening an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues) may elicit a faster response.

Comment: I try to minimize the creation of issues whenever I hit a problem with a library. At this point I am trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong, or if this might be a bug.